# How to replace plugins in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am working on a website built on wordpress in which I want to replace some plugins. The reason behind the replacement of those plugins as it is no longer developed. The most important plugin which I want to replace is `Accordion Shortcodes`.

From the [tutorial](https://wordpress.org/plugins/accordion-shortcodes/) mentioned here,

Accordion Shortcodes is a simple plugin that adds a few shortcodes for adding accordion drop-downs to your pages.

The accordions should blend seamlessly with your theme. However, you may want to edit your theme’s main stylesheet in order to add some custom styling (see below for sample CSS).

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what best practice I need to follow in order to replace a plugin in wordpress. Also, what would be the best replacement for `Accordion Shortcodes`, `Modify Attachments Meta` ?

Comment: Try searching on the official WordPress.org plugins [page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) - just use the proper keyword based on what the specific plugin is for/doing. No two plugins are exactly the same, but focus on the features they offer, and see if they can help you achieve similar results.

Answer (score 3):

John, Your title says "How' and the above two answers describe "how". However reading the text implies you want people to tell what plugins are best to replace your existing plugins with.  As the comment says, plugins do not always 'replace' each other exactly and may have many more features. Judging by the names of the plugins, I think you need to understand why and how those plugins are being used. An approach:

1. Discuss with the site owner what features they care about and what are 'nice to have'.  They may not know which plugins are delivering which aspects of the website, so very important to know what are the absolutely important aspects.  They may no longer need some of those plugins (eg: Modify Attachments Meta? might be a tool used to do something and no longer needed?)
2. Assess what features are being delivered by each of the outdated plugins, and which are important or non essential.
3. Research for alternate plugins that provide the features that are important
4. Review the best candidates and test them on test copy of main site.
5. Work out what if any conversion may be required.  EG: if's access control, how is it doing the access control? how would you convert that?
6. Test the conversion, test the new plugins on converted data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple deactivate plugin and then remove the plugin.
Here is a plugin suggestion 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/accordions/
You can use this plugin instead of that outdated version of the Accordion Shortocdes plugin.

Please let me know it helps to you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am wondering how do you come up with a conclusion that https://wordpress.org/plugins/accordions would be best replacement for my outdated version of `Accordion Shortcodes`.

Comment: Are you around ?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I'm here.  I am not the owner of suggested plugin, But I have checked both plugins, One you are using and another one I have suggested. I feel that the suggested plugin has lot's of features than current one plugin which you are using.
That's why I suggested.
Please let me know if you need any other info.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this and yes it completely makes sense what you have said. I am wondering if you have any suggestion for the following plugins `Modify Attachments Meta;` `WordPress Access Control;`
`WordPress Access Control - Media extension;` ? I have very less knowledge about plugins as I haven't worked on plugins a lot in the past. Let me know if you have any suggestions for it otherwise I will look on internet.

Comment: Just checking if you have any recommendation for `WordPress Access Control;` `WordPress Access Control - Media extension;` Let me know if you have any suggestion on this.

Comment: These 2 plugins are no longer being developed and I want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I like to go about replacing plugins:

1. Identify any shortcodes it provides, and search your database (via either PhpMyAdmin, or a database search plugin like [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)) for that shortcode. This will identify all the posts & pages you'll probably need to update.
2. Save any custom CSS or other configuration data that might be relevant to the replacement.
3. Assuming there's no conflict between the old plugin and new one, install & activate the new plugin. Then you can begin replacing the usages of the old plugin one by one (and modifying the configuration of the new plugin to get it "just right").
4. After you've done *all* the replacements (which you might want to verify by another database search), deactivate and remove the old plugin.

This is how I do plugin migrations. In your case, in step 3, you could probably install *each* of the plugins you're considering, try them out, and only do the full migration for the one you like best.